# Locate Another Application's Data Directory

Tags: c#, windows-vista

Given an application "Foo" which can be installed with or without a manifest (Into "Program Files") under windows Vista, which also has a subdirectory of the application install path "bar":

How can i locate the actual path of \foo\bar from a another (C#) application which does not use file and registry virtualization.

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: Not really; the idea is you shouldn't be messing with another applications data.

Comment: If you know the name of the assembly holding "Foo", you may be able to use Assembly.Location property to find the path.

Answer (score 0):

In system.IO, there is a method called [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w(v=vs.90).aspx).

You could use that to iterate through, checking for the name foo (if it's in the root directory), then going into bar.

If you need the drive names too, you could use [DriveInfo.GetDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.90).aspx). These should help you search for it. Example:

```
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(d.name, "foo\bar");
        foreach (string dir in dirs) 
        {
          //you have your foo bar!
        }
    }
```